# Concat firstname and lastname with space in between in oracle pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, concatenation

I have one requirement to concat user first_ name, and last_name with space in between in Oracle.
Ex: first_name is `'Hopkins'` and last_name is `'Joe'`.

Full name should be printed as Hopkins Joe.

I'm using Oracle 11g and it is working in SQL query, but not working in stored procedure.

Comment: try this first_name || '          ' || last_name

Comment: Show us your stored procedure

Answer (score 6):

**Try this:**

```
 SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(first_name, ' '),last_name)
```

**OR**

```
 SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_namefrom;
```

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for your answers. All solutions are working fine in normal sql query. But not working any solution in Store procedure. If I place this code store proc its giving compilation error. Please can you try to put your solutions in store procedures and post me..

Comment: @suddewarRamu Can u post your store procedure code??

Comment: What is "not working"? Please don't just say it's not working without giving the code you tried and the exact error message you got.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
TRIM(FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME)
```

if any of first_name or last_name is blank or null the extra space we are adding will be trimmed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select first_name || ' ' || last_name as full_name from table
```

Example:

```
SELECT 'Dave' || ' ' || 'Anderson' as full_name
FROM table;

Result: 'Dave Anderson'
```

Comment: Hi guys, almost all the solutions are working fine with minor changes that instead of select first_name || ' ' || last_name as full_name from table, I had do like select first_name || '' '' || last_name as full_name from table and instead of  SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(first_name, '' ''),last_name) I had to change to  SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(first_name, ' '),last_name). Anyhow thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use CONCAT function twice. Concat with space will work in this way

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name,(' '||last_name)) AS full_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
select first_name||' '||last_name
from table_name
where first_name is not null  -- "if the first_name can be null"
and   last_name is not null   -- "if the last_name can be null"
;
```

Comment: Hi guys, below is the store proc.

Comment: Below is the store proc.

Comment: create or REPLACE PROCEDURE concat_names
AS
BEGIN

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('empId is' || 1255);
  DBMS_output.put_line('Full Name is: ' || CONCAT(CONCAT('Hopkins', ' '),'Joe'));
  DBMS_output.put_line('Full Name with id is:  ' || 'Hopkins' || ' ' || 'Joe' ||' '|| 1255 );
END ;

set serveroutput on;
exec concat_names();

Comment: This is working fine in windows, but not in mac OS. Anyhow I will post the error tomorrow once I'm in office.